# OrderedDict updating all key-value pairs when only intended to update one key-value pair

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a python OrderedDict,and everything when I update only one key-value, all other key-value pairs get update as well. I have include both the source code and trace from below.

I am expecting to have a key-pair of (2014, {'start': 2014, 'end': 2015}), but this is not the case here.

```
import datetime
import collections
import math
from decimal import Decimal
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta



def get_ordered_dict(start, end, intial_value):
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        d[i] = intial_value
    return d


start_year = 2014
end_year = start_year + 39 + 1
od = get_ordered_dict(start_year, end_year, {} )

for year in od.keys():
    print year
    d = od[year]
    d['start'] = year
    d['end'] = year + 1
    print od
```

Returns:

```
OrderedDict([(2014, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2015, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2016, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2017, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2018, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2019, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2020, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2021, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2022, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2023, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2024, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2025, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2026, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2027, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2028, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2029, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2030, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2031, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2032, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2033, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2034, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2035, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2036, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2037, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2038, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2039, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2040, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2041, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052}),
             (2042, {'end': 2053, 'start': 2052})])
```

Comment: All keys have reference to same dictionary instance as it's value.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
def get_ordered_dict(start, end, intial_value):
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        d[i] = intial_value
    return d
```

you assign to each and every `d[i]` a reference to the same `initial_value`, the same dictionary in this case

```
od = get_ordered_dict(start_year, end_year, {})
```

So in your loop you modify the very same dictionary over and over again.

One way to assign a unique dictionary reference would be to make a (shallow) copy of the `initial_value`:

```
d[i] = intial_value.copy()  # [sic]
```

You could also make `initial_value` a keyword argument that defaults to `None`:

```
def get_ordered_dict(start, end, intial_value=None):
    ...
        # assuming intial_value will always be a dict
        d[i] = intial_value.copy() if intial_value is not None else {}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, could you provide a suitable solution? Even tips for fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, use instead `d[i] = intial_value.copy()` to ensure that each entry is  a different empty dict.